# Set conditions on xpath statement

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

I am scraping a website using scrapy and would like to only grab the data from the links that are grayed out which I have done by targeting the css class for the grayed elements. The issue I am facing is the second xpath `/div[1]/text()` is selecting the elements from the elements that are active, so when my list returns I have the address for the companies that are not active in my list.

What I would like to know is if there is a way to only select the parent div from the class font_grey. I did try using `parent::text()` but that returned an empty value.

```
<div onclick="" class="col-md-5 border_right maxhelem ">
<h3 class="font_grey">Kost A/S</h3>
501&nbsp;Give St
</div>

response.xpath('//*[@id="main_wrapper"]/main/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/h3[@class="font_grey"]/text() |  //*[@id="main_wrapper"]/main/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//div[h3/@class = "font_grey"]
```

will select all `div` elements with a child `h3` element that has a `@class` attribute value of `"font_grey"`.

Comment: is there a way to add normalize-space() to that?

Comment: To achieve what goal?

Answer (score 1):

> if there is a way to only select the parent div from the class font_grey

Try this xpath `//*[@class='font_grey]/..`

Explanation:

`//*` - any element at any level
`[@class='font_grey']` - where class attribute is equal to "font_grey"
`/..` - select parent